# How to use tesseract on Windows without using the executable?

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

Does anyone know how can i use tesseract on Windows without using the `.exe`

I want to use pytesseract for a Proof of concept on my company's system where i don't have access to install the executable.

Please suggest any alternative here ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your restriction is installing any exe (and I assume that you tried to install python), you can start to learn how to work with notebooks, and use a cloud-based notebook.
You can use google colab for free https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tesseract-ocr-data python package,
tho it is quite big.